# Silverlight & JS: Get the <RowDefinitions> Name or uid from XAML, through Javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, uid, xname

I am trying to obtain the <RowDefinitions> element from my Xaml, through Javascript, so I can add new <RowDefinition> elements to it at runtime.

This way, if a user inputs the number '20', then 20 <RowDefinition> elements will be added to <RowDefinitions>.

The problem is that <RowDefinitions> does not have a possibility for x:Name. It only has x:uid. So would it be possible to fetch the uid from within Javascript? I need the <RowDefinitions> Element one way or another (but only through JS). I need to add <RowDefinition> elements to it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: With the vast majority of Silverlight development now using the Managed API where apps a released in XAP files, it would be helpful of you explicitly indicate whether you are using much older Javascript API or if you need help with the HtmlBridge of the Managed API.

Comment: I am using the much older Javascript API (Silverlight 1.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming Javascript API**

There is no such element as `<RowDefinitions>` you will be refering to the `RowDefinitions` property of a `Grid` element which is represented as `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` in Xaml.  Hence you use FindName to aquire the `Grid` then use `GetValue` to get the collection of row definitions.  Lets assume you have this simple Xaml to start with:-

```
<Grid
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Loaded="rootGridLoaded" />
```

So in your Javascript you have can have this code:-

```
function rootGridLoaded(sender)
{
     var plugin = sender.getHost();
     var rowDefs = sender.GetValue("RowDefinitions");
     for (var i=0; i < 20; i++)
     {
         var rowDef = plugin.content.createFromXaml("<RowDefinition />");
         rowDefs.add(rowDef);
     }
}
```

This will get the `RowDefinitions` collection from the `Grid` (which in this case is the sender but you just as easily have used `FindName` to get a named grid.  Then it loops adding 20 `RowDefintion` instances ot the collection.

Comment: @MrSilverlight if this answer solved your problem, than mark it as right.